# ARM and dual e-ink displays

Tags: arm, display, e-ink

Is it possible to have an ARM SBC drive two e-ink displays?  With the low costs e-readers like the B&N Nook Touch, I am interested in buying two just to extract the e-ink displays.  The only problem is I don't know how to go about getting an ARM SBC to drive two e-ink displays.  Any thoughts?

Comment: There seems to be no accessible information about the display used in the B&N readers. Do you have any information about the display? How often do you want to refresh each display?

Comment: I think your best chance is hacking the Nook to accept & display data, everything I've seen with e-Ink displays is that they are still very protective of the technology and only licensing it to the likes of Amazon / B&N. Someone hacked a Kindle to act as a screen for a RaspberryPi, that might give you a start. Also look up the Motorola F3 phones, they're the cheapest source of e-ink displays.